# Помогите с кодировкой utf-8 в базе данных mysql

Tags: mysql

Ошибка где, то в базе данных, так как обычный html код на русском.
В базе данных, если, что кодировка utf8_general_ci
Кто знает, в чем проблема, отпишитесь, пожалуйста

Подключение к БД

```
class database{
public $host = db_host;
public $username = db_user;
public $password = db_pass;
public $db_name = db_name;

public $link;
public $error;

/*
 * Class Constructor
 */
public function __construct(){
    //Call Connect Function
    $this->connect();
}

/*
 * Connector
 */
private function connect() {
    $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

    if(!$this->link) {
        $this->error = "Connection Failed: ".$this->link->connect_error;
        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Select
 */
public function select($query) {
    $result = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        return $result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Insert
 */
public function insert($query) {
    $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

    //Validate Insert
    if($insert_row) {
        header("Location: index.php?msq=".urlencode('Record insert'));
        exit();
    }
}

/*
 * Update
 */
public function update($query) {
    $update_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

    //Validate update
    if($update_row) {
        header("Location: index.php?msq=".urlencode('Record update'));
    }
}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте после подключения к БД:

```
private function connect() {
    $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
    $this->link->set_charset("utf8");
    if(!$this->link) {
        $this->error = "Connection Failed: ".$this->link->connect_error;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Файлы со скриптами сохраняйте в кодировке `UTF-8 (без BOM)`

Comment: Пишет, что не может подключиться к серверу

Comment: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Comment: Напишите часть кода подключения к БД в своем вопросе

Comment: Код выше написал, посмотрите

Comment: Вы написали константы. Приведите больше кода

Comment: Извините не то написал, вот, константы у меня в отдельном коде просто

Comment: обновил ответ исходя из условий

Comment: Спасибо, большое, очень вам благодарен